# How do I get D3 Data Driven Document to display a moment.js datetime in the correct time zone?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime, d3.js, momentjs

I am developing an AngularJS single page application which uses `D3` charts to display data that was recorded in different time zones throughout the world.  The time axis on the chart needs to display the time in its original time zone.

The data to plot is an array of value,timestamp pairs. The timestamp contains its own time zone information and is encoded in `ISO format` (e.g. `"2003-12-14T12:00:00.000+08:00"`).  So the json appears something like this:

```
"values": [
   ["2003-12-14T12:00:00.000+08:00", 10],
   ["2003-12-14T13:00:00.000+08:00", 20],
   ["2003-12-14T14:00:00.000+08:00", 30],
   ["2003-12-14T15:00:00.000+08:00", 40],
   ["2003-12-14T16:00:00.000+08:00", 50]
]
```

The time stamp and value are then added to an object, where the time stamp is converted to a moment:

```
data = values[1];
timeStamp = moment.parseZone(values[0]);
```

These samples are then passed to `D3` for display.  However, when they are passed to `D3`, the time ticks are displayed in local browser time.  This is no good - and I can't work out how to get it to display the data in the correct time zone.

I have tried setting the `xAxis.tickFormat` with a custom method, but the time that is passed to it is a standard Javascript Date object, in the local time zone.

In addition, the time zone may change in the middle of the chart (due to DST), so it is not possible to simply hold the value for the time zone offset and make a manual adjustment.

Comment: Have you seen [this post](http://blog.cortexintel.com/blog/2014/09/local-timezones-with_d3js/)?

Comment: Thanks @LarsKotthoff - that really helped.  Solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to write a method which calculates and returns the tick values, and similarly the tick formats, as given by [this link](http://blog.cortexintel.com/blog/2014/09/local-timezones-with_d3js/) from @LarsKotthoff.

The final code needs to be something like this:

```
xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .tickValues(calculateTickValue)
    .tickFormat(getTickFormat);

var getTickFormat = function(date){
    var diff = date.format("DD") != previousDate.format("DD");                    
    if (diff){
        previousDate = date;
        return date.format("MMM Do, HH:mm");
    }
    return date.format(tickFormat);
}

var calculateTickValue = function(){
    var startTime = scope.segment.startTime;
    var endTime = scope.segment.endTime;
    var tickValues = [];
    var difference = moment.duration(endTime.diff(startTime));
    var maximumTicks = calculateMaximumTicks(); 
    if (difference.asHours() >= maximumTicks){
       tickValues = calculateHoursTicks(startTime, endTime, maximumTicks);
       tickFormat = "HH:mm";
    }
    else {
        tickValues = caclulateMinutesTicks(startTime, endTime, maximumTicks);
        tickFormat = "HH:mm";
    }

    previousDate = startTime;
    return tickValues;
}
```

Obviously, depending upon the scale you need this can be customised for years, months, days, hours etc.